# Alt symbols don't always work

Tags: windows, symbols

Pressing Alt + 254 should produce ■ symbol.

And it usually does.

But in some applications it produces þ.

Why is that and how can I always make the ■ without copying it around?

Shouldn't Alt symbols be universally working? What would be an alternative symbols that would work in any situation?

Comment: The "symbol" produced is reliant on the FONT that is being used and that is determined by the application choosing the font to be used.  Not all fonts have the same symbols at the same offsets.. in fact, if they did, there would be no need for fonts that render non latin chars at all.  Universal?  No.  If you are in windows, poke around `charmap` and see for yourself.  Good luck! :)  PS: adding a tag for what OS would help.

Comment: What OS? What applications is it working in, and which is it not working in?

Comment: This is on Windows. Most recently it doesn't want to type ■ in Keepass. Keepass also have an inbuild text file editor. Even if I change font it still types þ